# AutoMapper Map properties of nested objects if Not Null

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

I have the following sample objects..

```
  public class ComplexObject
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SimpleObject Child1 { get; set; }
    public SimpleObject Child2 { get; set; }
  }
  public class SimpleObject : IEquatable< SimpleObject >
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
  }
```

with the following AutoMapper configuration

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<SimpleObject, SimpleObject>()
    .ForAllMembers(expression=>expression.Condition(r=>!r.IsSourceValueNull));

  Mapper.CreateMap<ComplexObject, ComplexObject>()
    .ForAllMembers(expression=>expression.Condition(resolutionContext=>!resolutionContext.IsSourceValueNull));
```

and the following NUnit test...

```
[SetUp] public void Should_run_before_each_test()
{
  child1 = new SimpleObject { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Smith", Age = 34, Gender = "Male" };
  child2 = new SimpleObject { FirstName = "Andy", LastName = "Smith-bob", Age = 21, Gender = "Male" };
}

[ Test ]
public void Should_ignore_null_properties_in_nested_objects()
{
  var source = new ComplexObject()
  {
    Name = "blue",
    Child1 = new SimpleObject{FirstName = "dot", LastName = "net"}
  };
  var destination = new ComplexObject()
  {
    Name = "Andy",
    Child1 = child1,
    Child2 = child2
  };

  destination = Mapper.Map(source, destination);

  destination.Name.Should(Be.EqualTo(source.Name));
  destination.Child1.FirstName.Should(Be.EqualTo("dot"));
  destination.Child1.LastName.Should(Be.EqualTo("net")  );
  destination.Child1.Age.Should(Be.EqualTo(child1.Age)  );
  destination.Child1.Gender.Should(Be.EqualTo(child1.Gender)  );
}
```

The above test fails when asserting the age as AutoMapper is pushing null through to the destination object.

Am I expecting too much from AutoMapper, or have I missed some vital map configuration step.

The ultimate goal is to have a very complex domain object bound to incoming form data via an MVC action. AutoMapper will then be used to merge only non-null properties (at all depths of the object graph) into the real instance being maintained throughout a multi step form.

Just in case anyone needs to know... I have also tried the following mapping configuration without any luck :(

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<ComplexObject, ComplexObject>()
    .ForMember(x=>x.Child1, l=>l.ResolveUsing(x=>x.Child1 == null?null:Mapper.Map<SimpleObject,SimpleObject>(x.Child1)))
    .ForMember(x=>x.Child2, l=>l.ResolveUsing(x=>x.Child2 == null?null:Mapper.Map<SimpleObject,SimpleObject>(x.Child2)))
    .ForAllMembers(expression=>expression.Condition(resolutionContext=>!resolutionContext.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect the value on the destination object is not null if the source value is null? The default value for `int?` is `null`, and therefore, when you call

`destination.Child1.Age.Should(Be.EqualTo(child1.Age));`

The `.Should` is what's failing. This should be expected behavior.

Try something like `Assert.Null(detination.Child1.Age)`, and it should pass. AutoMapper is not 'pushing' the value through, there is no source value and therefore, `Age` is just going to have it's default value.

Comment: nope.. not when I'm trying to convince AutoMapper to ignore null source values as per the attempted mapping below..

`Mapper.CreateMap<SimpleObject, SimpleObject>()
    .ForAllMembers(expression=>expression.Condition(r=>!r.IsSourceValueNull));`

Comment: Can you add what you have assigned to `child1` and `child2`?

Comment: The problem is that in your example, it's not mapping `SimpleObject` to `SimpleObject`, it's mapping `ComplexObject` to `ComplexObject`. Because `source.Child1` is not null, it just assigns it to `destination.Child1`.

Comment: Yeh.. I too had got that far... I was under the presumption that AutoMapper would/should handler deeper type mappings...

Comment: It's one of the reasons that I tried the more complex mapping with resolvers attached to each of the child objects... that still fails :(

Comment: From this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463183/merge-two-objects-to-produce-third-using-automapper it looks like the ValueInjector project could do exactly what you need.